# javascript validation not reading other conditions on my if else if

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

what could be wrong I tried to validate the input fields name, company_name, password, when I'm on the password field it says password should not be empty but I already inputted some characters on the password input field.

it doesn't seem to read the validation for `password.length` and `password != confirm_password` condition on my else if

here's my code

```
$('#button-parent a').bind('click',function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var prev = current;
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var company_name =  document.getElementById('company_name').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;


        if( name == null || name == "") {
                alert('name is required');
                return false;

        } else if( name.length < 5) {
                alert('name must be atleast 6 characters');
                return false;

        } else if( company_name == null || company_name == ""){
                alert('company name is required');
                return false;

        } else if ( password == null || password == ""){
                alert('password field should not be empty');
                return false;

        } else if ( password.length < 8 ) {
                alert('password must be atleast 8 characters');
                return false;

        } else if ( password != confirm_password ) {
                alert('Password do not match');
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: if you want to check for empty password check the length you have it already

Comment: As an aside, all of those `null` checks are unnecessary because the `.value` of an input will never be `null`.

Comment: hi guradio i already remove the condition if( password == null || password == "" ) and i enter morethan 8 characters on the password field and the alert is password must be atleast 8 characters that the alert it should not appear right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rIf you are using jQuery why don't you get the values from $() selector?

```
$(function() { 
    $('#button-parent a').bind('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var prev = current;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var company_name = $('#company_name').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var confirm_password = $('#confirm_password').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        var errorMsg = '';
        if (name == null || name == "") {
          errorMsg += 'name is required\n';
        }
        if (name.length < 5) {
          errorMsg += 'name must be atleast 6 characters\n';
        }
        if (company_name == null || company_name == "") {
          errorMsg += 'company name is required\n';

        }
        if (password == null || password == "") {
          errorMsg += 'password field should not be empty\n';

        }
        if (password.length < 8) {
          errorMsg += 'password must be atleast 8 characters\n';

        }
        if (password != confirm_password) {
          errorMsg += 'Password do not match';
        }
        if (errorMsg != '') {
          alert(errorMsg);
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This way you can show all the errors in the form at once and the users will not be irritated at all.

Comment: i use the getElementByid because jquery selector doesn't get the value the name and company name seems ok but when it comes down to password field alert is popping up i did enter morethan 8 characters and there's no error as well what could be wrong?

Comment: Ok I think you are not working inside document.ready... See my edited code You have to use jQuery inside $(function(){}) to get the proper results from your elements

Comment: before it was working fine i dont know what happened.. by the way Ive tried to replace my code to your edited code still now working

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) for your page, I can then see what is going on with the HTML

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/lestah/04a6z1yc/embed/"></script>

Comment: did you see the html form and javascript i wrote?

Comment: I did but it has errors in there, can you please fix that.

Comment: this is my first time to use js fiddle sorry progrAmmar could you tell me what was the error?

Comment: Can you tell me if you are calling the jquery library before you are doing this validation?

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> i added that on the head of html

Comment: Turns out the error was on my part, in the `if` statements I was calling `erroMsg` rather than `errorMsg` I have updated my mistake kindly check it again

Comment: Hey progrAmmar i found out what the problem from password down to the last field i use jquery.val again with the same variable names on my validation that's why it was overwritten i send. btw thanks for u help as well how do i commend u

Comment: That's great that it's solved. No commendation required :D just mark the post as answer. That will be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following line of code instead since you are using jQuery.

```
var password = $('#password').val();
```

For a quick check to see if this line works, you can type and run this command at the console section of the developer tool. If it works you should be seeing the input value.